# Looking for a short story about a ring and a giant

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I have been trying to find this short story for ages.

I forget most of the detail but it is set in space and in the end the protagonist has the realisation that the star he sees (or the planet he is on?) is just a glint in the jewel of a ring worn on the hand of a man (giant?)

Has anyone any knowledge of this story?

Comment: This is very sparse. Might I suggest you have a read through [How to ask a good story-ID question?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and use the checklists to see if you can add anything. Do you recall anything about the protagonist? / Why they were in space? / How they got to space? / Where they were living in space? / What age was the protagonist? / What race/species was the protagonist? / Whether the story was aimed at adults or children? / Where you might have read the story? / When you read the story.